# Define new key binding for new minor mode

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, minor-mode

I am writing my first minor mode, and would like to understand how to bind a key to an action in that mode.

```lisp
(define-minor-mode hello-mode
  "My Mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Hello"
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (define-key map (kbd "M-p")
              (lambda ()
                (interactive)
                (message "HI!!!")))
            map)
  :group 'hello)
```

After running this followed by `M-x hello-mode` (or `(hello-mode t)`), I would hope that hitting `M-p` would display `"HI!!!"` in the echo area, but Emacs tells me `M-p` is still undefined.

What else is needed to bind a key to a function when my minor mode is active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, for me. Did you try it in `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

And if I load library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) and then use `M-k hello-mode-map` it shows me that `M-p` is bound to an (anonymous) command.

However, I recommend that you give your keymap a name (a symbol). That helps users (and yourself) more.

---

(If you have an Emacs 28 preview then you also have that command, `describe-keymap` - it's been added to Emacs itself.)

Comment: It was very helpful to me to know it worked for someone else.  Restarted Emacs with a minimal config, then my full config, and it worked with no issues (!!).

Comment: @JohnJ: `define-minor-mode` generates a `defvar` when `:keymap` specifies a keymap value directly.  As evaluating a `defvar` doesn't overwrite an existing value for that variable, re-evaluating the `define-minor-mode` form with an updated keymap value won't change any existing value of that variable.  This probably explains what was happening for you.  Note that you can `(makunbound 'VAR)` if necessary.